# How to parse only specific tag values?

Tags: android, xml

I want to parse only `Margherita` tag-related values. It is possible to parse tag-related values?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <menu>
<item>
    <id>1</id>   
    <name>Margherita</name>
    <cost>155</cost>
    <description>Single cheese topping</description>
 </item>
 <item>
    <id>6</id>   
    <name>Margherita</name>
    <cost>155</cost>
    <description>Single cheese topping</description>
</item>
<item>
    <id>8</id>   
    <name>Margherita</name>
    <cost>1535</cost>
    <description>Single cheese topping</description>
</item>
<item>
    <id>2</id>   
    <name>Double Cheese Margherita</name>
    <cost>22e5</cost>
    <description>Loaded with Extra Cheese</description>
</item>
<item>
    <id>3</id>   
    <name>Fresh Veggie</name>
    <cost>110</cost>
    <description>Oninon and Crisp capsicum</description>
 </item>
 <item>
    <id>4</id>   
    <name>Peppy Paneer</name>
    <cost>155</cost>
    <description>Paneer, Crisp capsicum and Red pepper</description>
 </item>
 <item>
    <id>5</id>   
    <name>Mexican Green Wave</name>
    <cost>445</cost>
    <description>Onion, Crip capsicum, Tomato with mexican herb</description>
 </item>
 </menu>
```

In the above XML, I want to show only values related to the `Margherita` tags. It this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code, it's a simple java project, not android, but it works for me!

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class test {
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("D:/Xml.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :"
                + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0)
                        .getTextContent().equals("Margherita")) {
                    System.out.println("Id: "
                            + eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0)
                                    .getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("It costs: "
                            + eElement.getElementsByTagName("cost").item(0)
                                    .getTextContent());
                    System.out.println(eElement
                            .getElementsByTagName("name").item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Description:"
                            + eElement.getElementsByTagName("description")
                                    .item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println();
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice to use [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) library, and model some data classes to bind to xml.

Item class:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="item")
public class Item{

    @Element(name = "id", required = true)
    public int id;

    @Element(name = "name", required = true)
    public String name;

    @Element(name = "cost", required = true)
    public double cost;

    @Element(name = "description", required = true)
    public String desc;
}
```

Menu class:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

import java.util.List;

@Root(name="menu")
public class Menu{
    @ElementList(inline = true,type = Item.class)
    public List<Item> items;
}
```

De-serialize it to objects:

```
Serializer srl = new Persister();

//--- Placed menu.xml in /assets for a test ---
//--- you can obtain it from somewhere else like a web server etc also ---  
InputStream ips = getAssets().open("menu.xml");

Menu menu = srl.read(Menu.class,ips);

if(menu != null && menu.items != null){

    for (Item i : menu.items){

        if(i.name != null && i.name.contains("Margherita")){
            //--do something with this item--
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case a sax - parser would be a better choice:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

because you can "skip" the items that you don't want to use anyway.